# Merging datasets by columns that have different names

Tags: r, merge

I want to merge datasets by columns that have different names

For example, for the data frames, df and df1

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3), Day = c(1,2,3), mean = c(2,3,4))
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3), Day = c(1,2,3), median = c(5,6,7))
```

I want to merge df and df1 so that I get

```
ID  Day  Measure  Value
1   1    Mean      2
2   2    Mean      3
3   3    Mean      4
1   1    Median    5    
2   2    Median    6    
3   3    Median    7
```

Any ideas how? I tried using

```
merge(df,df1, by=c("ID","Day"))   and
rbind.fill(df,df1)  from the plyr package
```

but they each only do half of what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(tidyr)
m <- merge(df, df1, c("ID", "Day"))
gather(m, measure, value, mean:median)
#  ID Day measure value
#1  1   1    mean     2
#2  2   2    mean     3
#3  3   3    mean     4
#4  1   1  median     5
#5  2   2  median     6
#6  3   3  median     7
```

And with `reshape2`:

```
melt(m, id=c("ID", "Day"))
```

Or with `data.table`:

```
setDT(df, df1)
setkey(df, ID, Day)
melt(df[df1], c("ID", "Day"))
# 1:  1   1     mean     2
# 2:  2   2     mean     3
# 3:  3   3     mean     4
# 4:  1   1   median     5
# 5:  2   2   median     6
# 6:  3   3   median     7
```

Comment: how about a data.table answer? e.g. using the new on argument would make this super easy. would post myself but I'm on phone.

Answer (score 1):

In base R:

```
vars <- c("ID","Day")
m <- merge(df, df1, by=vars)
cbind(m[vars], stack(m[setdiff(names(m),vars)]) )

#  ID Day values    ind
#1  1   1      2   mean
#2  2   2      3   mean
#3  3   3      4   mean
#4  1   1      5 median
#5  2   2      6 median
#6  3   3      7 median
```

Answer (score -1):

You could add a new column to your two original data.frames called "Measure", then set the entire column to "Mean" in your first data.frame and "Median" in your second data.frame. Then set the colname of mean and median in both of your data.frames to "Value". Then combine using rbind.